# understanding windowed fourier ridges

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier

I am studying windowed Fourier ridges for my project. I know that it computes the instantaneous frequencies and amplitudes from the spectrogram. But I don't really know how it relates to signal processing, can anyone explain this concept to me?

Comment: This is a wide open question, could you please clarify what it is you would like an answer for?

Comment: Image restoration using windowed Fourier transform

Comment: What exactly about Image restoration using the DFT don't you understand? Is there an algorithmic problem, or an issue you face? For example, why do you need the instantaneous frequencies/amplitudes from the spectrogram?